# Slick Slider onChange

Tags: jquery, html, slick.js

So I'm building a slider for a client and the functionality is a bit more than I had thought, Basically the image slider is 3 sliders that all function together. I need to start the slider that's on the far right at the next slide not the same slide that is loaded. So basically on load the girl with the glasses shows, the next slide is the girl with the curly hair. The far right slider needs to show the next slide and not the current slide. What i'm trying to build is in the screenshot.

The swipe on the photos should slide the content on the left side as well (which it's doing), i just need to figure out the slide offset, I'm assuming the onchange function is what i will need. I just need help setting it up. Any advice is much appreciated. Below is my code or you can check codepen in comment

```js
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider-content').slick({
   slidesToShow:1,
   fade: true,
   asNavFor:'.slider-images,.slider-images-two'
  });


  $('.slider-images').slick({
   slidesToShow: 1,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   asNavFor: '.slider-content,.slider-images-two',
   centerMode: true,
   focusOnSelect: true,
   arrows: false,
   useCss: true,
   useTransform: true,
   centerPadding: '0%',
   infinite: true,
   // cssEase: 'linear',
  });

  $('.slider-images-two').slick({
   slidesToShow: 1,
   slidesToScroll: 1,
   asNavFor: '.slider-content, .slider-images',
   centerMode: true,
   focusOnSelect: true,
   arrows: false,
   useCss: false,
   useTransform: false,
   centerPadding: '0%',
   infinite: true,
   // cssEase: 'linear',
  });

  var currentSlideTop = $('.slider-images').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
  var currentSlideBottom = $('.slider-images-two').slick('slickCurrentSlide');
  console.log('top-' + currentSlideTop);
  console.log('bottom-' + currentSlideBottom);
 });
```

```css
  body { background-color: #aacccc;overflow-x: hidden; }


  .slider-images .slick-active .content img{
   width: 352px;
   height: 440px;
  }
  .slider-images-two .slick-slide{
   width: 320px;
   height: 400px;
  }
  .slider-images-two .slick-slide .content img{
   opacity: .6;
      margin-left: auto;
  }
  .container-custom{
   max-width: 1180px;
   /*margin: 0 0 0 auto;*/
   margin: auto;
  }
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css">

<div class="container-custom" style="margin-top:6rem;">
 <div class="row align-content-center">
  <div class="col-lg-6">
   <div class="slider-contents-left">
     <div class="slider-content">
       <div>Host allowed me to see more of the country while working1</div>
       <div>I love matching people to the new exciting role they deserve2</div>
       <div>Host allowed me to see more of the country while working3.</div>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
   <div class="slider-contents-right">
    <div class="slider-images">
     <div>
      <div class="content">
       <img class="slider-image" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/600">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div>
      <div class="content">
       <img class="slider-image" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/600">
      </div>
     </div>
     <div>
      <div class="content">
       <img class="slider-image" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/600">
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2">
   <div class="slider-images-two">
    <div>
     <div class="content">
      <img class="slider-image" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/600">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div>
     <div class="content">
      <img class="slider-image" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/600">
     </div>
    </div>
    <div>
     <div class="content">
      <img class="slider-image" src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/600">
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>








 <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
 <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.slick/1.5.9/slick.min.js"></script>
 
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

What i'm trying to accomplish

[image]

Comment: https://codepen.io/kevinmlove/pen/NWWyoWd

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but surely this can be accomplished with 2 carousels. The primary carousel would be the testimonials using the `asNavFor` option for the photo gallery. What would the third one be for?